# Mounting a unionfs hides ALL lower-layer files

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I have partitions in `/dev/mmcblk0p5` and `/dev/mmcblk0p7`. I would like to union them together such that `p5` is read-only and `p7` holds the changes. I'm mounting `p5` on `/ro-root` and `p7` on `/root-overlay`.

```
/ # mount
/dev/mmcblk0p7 on /root-overlay type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mmcblk0p5 on /ro-root type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/ #
```

I have files in `/ro-root`:

```
/ # ls /ro-root
bin         etc         lost+found  opt         sbin        tmp         www
boot        home        media       proc        srv         usr
dev         lib         mnt         run         sys         var
/ #
```

`/root-overlay` is currently an empty filesystem.

I mount the union with:

```
mount -t unionfs -o dirs=/root-overlay=rw:/ro-root=ro none /real-root/
```

However, `/real-root` appears empty! If I create a file there, I can see it created in `/root-overlay` as well.

It seems that no matter what directories I try to union together, I only see files from the left-most directory of the `dirs=` parameter to mount.

Why are the files in `/ro-root` being hidden in the union?

Comment: You could also try with `aufs`.

Comment: another way to go is with LVM and create snapshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by @MariusMatutiae right syntax is `mount -t unionfs -o dirs=/branch_rw=rw:/branch_ro=ro unionfs /union`.
If you still get the same result, this may be a bug. Try delete and recreate directory `/root-overlay`.  Note `unionfs` is bit older. There are two new alternatives **aufs** (another union file system)  and **overlayfs**. Overlayfs is currently used by many OS's like Ubuntu. For ubuntu it is available by default, so you don't need to install it.

Usage example : overlayfs
`mount -t overlayfs overlayfs /real-root -o lowerdir=/ro-root,upperdir=/root-overlay`

Comment: According to the documentation from unionfs, "none" is correct. See http://git.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/?p=unionfs-3.15.y.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/filesystems/unionfs/usage.txt;h=1adde69e1ea60c7694bf2b5b246b88ec41c4b9d0;hb=HEAD

Comment: I'm in a tough position - I ended up moving on to aufs which is working, and it's not so easy to test these answers out at the moment. The bounty period is over. I'll give the bounty to you since a) you could use a bit of rep :)  and b) you mentioned moving to aufs which is what I ended up doing even though it's not a "fix" for the original problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a few years since my last use of *unionfs*, but still I cannot recall the use of the keyword *none* in the mount command. To the best of my recollection, the appropriate command would have been:

```
  mount -t unionfs -o dirs=/root-overlay=rw:/ro-root=ro unionfs /real-root
```

Comment: It’s just cosmetics. You can try with `tmpfs` too, it’s great. ;)

Comment: According to the documentation from unionfs, "none" is correct. See http://git.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/?p=unionfs-3.15.y.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/filesystems/unionfs/usage.txt;h=1adde69e1ea60c7694bf2b5b246b88ec41c4b9d0;hb=HEAD